# How can I show html5 timeline control in Safari?

Tags: html, video, safari, stream, timeline

I'm using html5 video tag to display a stream broadcast (live) as follows:

`<video controls="controls" src="..." controlslist="nodownload" autoplay="true"></video>`

But I can't see the timeline control (only I see is the text 'Live streaming') in Safari, so users cannot go back if they had missed some part of the stream.
Do you know if Safari supports this feature?

(when the video is not live stream, I can see the timeline control)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What type of steam is it - DASH, HLS, other?

Comment: The steam is HLS

Comment: It seems is an existing issue. I found out others users having this problem too (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11731)

Comment: Most browsers won't play HLS natively so a separate player is needed but Safari will as you note. It can be useful to test in a separate player on a different browser to make sure the stream itself supports the seeking backwards, Are you able to share the URL or an example HLS stream that does not work?

Comment: Yeah, I think is a Safari's problem. 'Cause on others browsers the stream is played correctly (showing the seekbar). I'm afraid I cannot share an example HLS because you'll need to access via VPN.

Comment: Most other browser can't play a HLS (a .m3u8) file natively, so the playback will usually be via a 3rd party Java script player. It may be worth checking if whatever player you are using also works on Safari. Note, that many streaming servers will provide separate MPEG DASH steams for Chrome and Edge and android, and HLS for iOS and Safari so that can explain different behaviour also.

Comment: Sure. I'll ask if we could use another player (3rd party one). It exceedes myself ha! I'll remain the question open for a while, maybe someone knows something about it. Thank you for your help Mick